# I am creating a database for a community to store details of all the members. What would be the best way to create such database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a database for a community to store details of all their members along with those members' relations with each other.

For Instance: There is a family of 4. Mother, Father, Son and Daughter. The Son gets married to a girl from another family in the same community (Their data is also in the same database). The newly married couple has a new member soon. Also they need to add their grand parents to the database at a later stage (Parents of both the Mother and Father in this case).

What would be the best way to create a schema for such a database.

I have a schema called member_details that'll store all community members' data in a single table something like this.

```
member_details: ID | Name | Birthdate | Gender | Father | Mother | Spouse | Child
```

All members would have relations mapped to Father,Mother,Spouse,Child referenced in the same table.

Is this schema workable from a technical pov?

I just need to know if my solution is correct or is there a better way to do this. I know there are a lot of websites storing this kind of data and if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Are the references to father/mother/spouse/child foreign keys? If so, there are better ways to store hierarchical data - see nested sets.

Comment: Also, don't use father/mother - that assumes there are two parents where there may be only one, or they may be guardians not parents, or they may be two people of the same gender. It feels like this should be normalised too (i.e. have a person table, a relationship table and a many-to-many between them).

Comment: @halfer I agree with the parents field being normalised or something like parent1 | parent2.

Also, the references to parents, spouse, child are in this same table. Every relation reference will be mapped to that member's ID.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advice you to use two tables. One for members of community and one for relations beetween them. Something like this:

```
Members:
ID | Name | Birth | Gender
```

```
Relations:
First Member ID | Second Member ID | Relation
```

Where you use IDs from first table as foreign keys in second. That way you'll be able to add more relations types when you need it. By the way, I'd add a third table to store relation types, so it can work as a dictionary. Same thing for genders.

Comment: I think there will be too many relations per person in this scenario. My father is my father, my grandfather's son and my mom's husband. That will require too many self joins so work it.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, "it depends".

The first question is "how will you use this data?". What sort of questions do you expect the database to answer? If you want to show a person's profile with their relationships, that's pretty easy. If you want to find out how many children a person has, or who is the grandfather of a person, or the age of someone's youngest child, that could be a little harder.

The second question is "how sure are you these are the only relationships you want to store?" Perhaps you also want to store "neighbour", "team member", "engaged_to" - or maybe you need to store that information later on. Maybe you need to take account of people getting divorced, or remarrying.

The schema you suggest works fine for most scenarios, but adding a new type of relationship means you have to add a new column. There are no hard and fast rules, but in general it's better to add rows than columns when faced with events in the problem domain. Asking "who is this person's grandfather" requires a couple of self joins, and that's okay.

@ba3a suggests splitting the information about people from the information about relationships. This is much "cleaner" - and less likely to require new columns as you store more types of relationship. Showing a person's profile requires a query with lots of outer joins. Finding a grand parent requires self joins on the "relations" table.

Comment: The DB is supposed to be used by the community to see details of their members.

For instance: I'll be looking at someone's details so I must be able to see and navigate to who their parents, spouse and children are. 

Also I wanted to know if this design will work for multiple relations to a single person.

Comment: Can you please give an example of "multiple relations to a single person?"

Comment: My father is related to my grandfather, mother, me and my siblings all at the same time.